# Do I need to install Vulkan for better performance?

Tags: drivers, games, performance, vulkan

afaik Vulkan is like DirectX. Will installing it be "like a drivers upgrade" for my system? I mean will my gaming performance be better? Some say it wouldn't and it's just intended for developers.

...also where do I install it for 14.04? Anyone knows some good PPA?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to install Vulkan's beta drivers manually (which I don't recommend you doing anyways) you can try out [this](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which appears to be a PPA that includes Vulkan.

At the moment I believe that Vulkan is in a beta stage and your improvements might be considered negligible in additional consideration that you may have some system instability.